# Kendo Multiselector focus out

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, focus, multi-select

I have this kendo multiselect and on mobile I would like that after select one item the virtual keyboard is being removed.

```
$("#multi").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: texts.CategoryPlaceholder,
    filter: "contains",
    select: function (e) {                    
        $("#multi").blur();
    },
    dataSource: myData
});
```

I also try to focus in a different element and didn´t work. The focus it´s not going out from the multiselector. I test the function triggered by the select event and it´s being called

Comment: hm, never worked with kendo for mobile...did you try to change focus like this: https://dojo.telerik.com/IQEhupUx

Comment: I try something very similar and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked as a fix. Thanks to @dev_in_progress

```
$("#multi").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: texts.CategoryPlaceholder,
    filter: "contains",
    change: function (e) {
        $("#multi").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataSource.filter({});
    },
    close: function (e) {            
        $("#btnToggleFilter").focus().blur();            
    },
    dataSource: myData
});
```

I had to add a filter reset on change event due a Bug on the control. This bug happen only on mobile and after typing and confirming it was selecting the wrong item of the list (always the first item)